# Why is my python code returning an import error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, importerror, newsapi

I am trying to access the python newsapi and I have registered, and gotten an api key. However, even when copy-pasting the code from the website into my code, it returns an import error. I am trying to make an app and this is causing a great inconvenience.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from newsapi import NewsApiClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'NewsApiClient' from 'newsapi' (/home/runner/CAC-Draft/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/newsapi/__init__.py)
```

My code:

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

# Init
newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='[API_KEY]')

# /v2/top-headlines
top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q='bitcoin',
                                          sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                          category='business',
                                          language='en',
                                          country='us')

# /v2/everything
all_articles = newsapi.get_everything(q='bitcoin',
                                      sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                      domains='bbc.co.uk,techcrunch.com',
                                      from_param='2017-12-01',
                                      to='2017-12-12',
                                      language='en',
                                      sort_by='relevancy',
                                      page=2)

# /v2/top-headlines/sources
sources = newsapi.get_sources()
```

I have put in a valid api key, I just kept it hidden to protect my account.

Comment: Do you have the newsapi-python module installed?

Comment: @ewong yes, i do

Answer (score -1):

I set the PYTHONPATH to '.' and that solved it for me.
`export PYTHONPATH='.'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using a Python interpreter from a virtual environment (venv), make sure you installed `newsapi-python` in the venv.

```bash
source venv/bin/activate

pip install newsapi-python

python <run your app>
```